# Scala and SBT install on Debian with Java 8

Tags: scala, installation, sbt, debian

I have java 8 server runtime on Debian.

Tried:
dpkg -i scala-2.11.7.deb

scala depends on java6-runtime-headless; however:
Package java6-runtime-headless is not installed.

But is ok:
scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.7 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

Now installing SBT from bintray repo:

My Java 8 is deactivated, installs open openjdk-7-* ...

Have to "apt-get purge openjdk-7-*" (wrong way)

EDIT: Problem corrected with:
update-alternatives --config java

Comment: EDIT: The scala install leaves an unmet dependency to java 6 ... apt-get -f install ... installs opend-jdk 7 again ... great!

Answer (score 8):

Here is the list of commands that I used to install in a clean Debian Jessie instance created using Vagrant:

#### Install Java 8

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-jessie.list` to replace `jessie` with `trusty` so that it will have the following line:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

And then execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Confirming that Java 8 is properly installed:

```
java -version
```

Which outputs:

```
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
```

#### Installing Scala 2.11.7:

```
wget -c www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.11.7.deb
sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.7.deb
```

This works fine to me and, just to confirm that I'm using the most recent version, I've executed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scala
```

And then:

```
scala -version
```

Which outputs:

```
Scala code runner version 2.11.7 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

#### Install SBT:

```
wget -c https://bintray.com/artifact/download/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.9.deb
sudo dpkg -i sbt-0.13.9.deb
```

Everything works as expected and then I've executed the following commands to ensure that I'm using the most recent version of SBT:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

At this point, Java 8, Scala and SBT were successfully installed on my machine.

Comment: You don't need to install scala, you can just use sbt which pulls in the scala version specified by your project.

Comment: @Reactormonk I know. I was trying to do exactly what he was trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't work as of 2019-10-28. Adding the PPA yields: *„[…]Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE 8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java (and the old links were broken by Oracle).THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED (unless I find some way around this limitation).“*

Comment: Another problem with this answer is that as of August 2021, bintray.com no longer supplies packages.

Comment: The answer works up until `wget -c https://bintray.com/artifact/download/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.9.deb` which no longer does anything: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden`