# How to install sbt 0.13.15 with oracle jdk

Tags: scala, java-8, sbt, installation

while installing sbt 0.13.15, it fails because it asks for openjdk-8. But I am running oracle jdk 8 and want to run sbt with it. How can I do this?

This error is shown

```
sbt depends on openjdk-8-jdk; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jdk is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package sbt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617146/scala-and-sbt-install-on-debian-with-java-8)?